# Replace brackets by Chinese brackets

Tags: xetex, unicode, newunicodechar

We are typesetting a document in Chinese. We are using `gb4e` and bibtex and want all brackets `(`and `)` to appear as Chinese brackets: `（` and `）`. I already found [Replace certain Unicode character with another in XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270418/replace-certain-unicode-character-with-another-in-xetex), but this does not seem to work for brackets.

`\newunicodechar{(}{（}`claims that ASCII is requested.

Answer (score 5):

`\newunicodechar` refuses to modify characters in the range 0–127, because they're used in TeX's syntax.

If you're brave, you can do the same by yourself:

```
\catcode`(=\active \catcode`)=\active
\protected\def({（} \protected\def){）}
```

at the end of your preamble.

Don't blame me if something goes wrong. ;-)

The simplest solution is “search and replace”, of course.

Comment: Hm. He should be *very* brave (and not use e.g. tikz) to do this. But as the question refers to gb4e and bibtex is it probable that only in this environments the parens should be changed but without a minimal example it is difficult to say.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I used *brave* on purpose. `;-)`

Comment: I know ;-). But I'm not sure if the OP would have realized that "brave" means "foolhardy" in this case -- after all he tried to redefine the parentheses with \newunicodechar, something I would dare to do.

Comment: Thanks. I am very brave (foolhardy) and it did not work. Copy & replace does not work since the Bibtex brackets are inserted by the bibtex style. I adapted gb4 and created a separate gb4e with Chinese brackets but this seem to be wrong since it does not address the general problem. I will post a minimal example as soon as I get to it.